# Is there an AdMob or other ad service SDK for Flutter apps

Tags: flutter

Hi I want to build a Flutter app but wanted to put some ads in my app can I do that with Flutter?  I was looking at react native and they have ads available but I can't find any information for Flutter.

Comment: As of Feb 13, 2017, we're not aware of a drop-in solution for Firebase Ads or AdMob for Flutter. It's on our radar. We encourage you to email flutter-dev@googlegroups.com and let us know this is something you need. Meanwhile, I've opened https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/8098 for you to subscribe. Thanks for the question!

Comment: Being able to implement [MoPub](https://www.mopub.com/) would be the most advantageous for developers because it allows the choice of integrating with many networks and maximizing relevancy of content and revenue.

Comment: There is one available now, for more details see: https://pub.dev/packages/admob_flutter

Answer (score 6):

I am not aware of any ad service SDKs specifically targeting Flutter today.

Flutter-using apps are just normal iOS or Android apps which happen to include a FlutterView, so ad frameworks using UIView or android.View playback systems should be possible to incorporate *next to* or (completely) on top of a FlutterView today.  hello_services in the Flutter examples has an example of placing other UIView or android.View objects next to the FlutterView object in the view hierarchy on iOS and Android:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/examples/hello_services

However there is no way to place UIView or android.View object inside or semi-transparently behind a FlutterView yet, and there are no written-in-Flutter ads players that I'm aware of.

If you were to attempt to integrate ads into Flutter-using App and had trouble, we would love too hear from you.  flutter.io lists many ways to contact the team (including Stack Overflow).

As Seth mentioned above there is a bug on file with Flutter about providing a good example of integrating ads and improving the ways to do so:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/8098

Answer (score 5):

There is now an AdMob plugin for Flutter underway here: https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/firebase_admob

Note, as of Sept 19, 2017, the plugin supports a subset of options and features, as the plugin is still a work in progress. We encourage you to check what the plugin supports before you start using it. Features and ideas welcome at https://flutter.io/issues

Comment: MoPub would be a key integration as it allows access to most major ad networks. I'm researching MoPub's [documentation for manual native ads integration](https://developers.mopub.com/docs/android/native/#method-3-manual-integration) in order to see if it is feasible to receive an ad on Android for  instance and pass that data via an [**EventChannel**](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/services/EventChannel-class.html) to Flutter in order to display.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use firebase admob plugin for flutter app.

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_admob#-example-tab-

You can check this video if you need to know how it gone a add to app.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rXYmbTBT3Yo